# install nsis on linux fails exitcode1

Tags: c++, linux, installation, nsis

I’m trying to install the Nsis on Linux,
I found a great guide to install from: http://www.xdevsoftware.com/blog/post/How-to-Install-the-Nullsoft-Installer---NSIS-on-Linux-.aspx
The problem is that its failing in the final step:
scons SKIPSTUBS=all SKIPPLUGINS=all SKIPUTILS=all SKIPMISC=all NSIS_CONFIG_CONST_DATA=no PREFIX=/usr/local/nsis/nsis-2.46 install-compiler

this is the output that i get:

```
Source/script.cpp:6460:1:   required from here
Source/util.h:145:1: error: 'close' was not declared in this scope, 
and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
```

The error is : ‘close’ was not declared in this scope….
I tried to run it a few times, and look up solution in the internet but I think there is a problem with that this a 64bit machine and not 32.

**any idea?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding `#include <unistd.h>` to util.h

There is a recent [bug report](http://sourceforge.net/p/nsis/bugs/1085/) about close() but that is on OSX and related to compiler/c++ library changes so I'm not sure if it applies but it might be worth looking into...